# Astra TabBar difficulty in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, tabs, flash-cs5, tabbar, yahoo-astra

I am having a difficult time getting the Astra TabBar to do anything except be able to pass in my DataProvider array.  I am trying to get it to simply trace a "click" using the CHANGE event when clicking on a tab.  Nothing happens and I'm not sure why.
Does anyone have experience with this, please?  My code looks like this:

```
package
{
import com.yahoo.astra.fl.controls.TabBar;
import com.yahoo.astra.fl.events.TabBarEvent;
public class TabBar extends Window
{
public var tabBarGpl:TabBar;
private function displayInit():void
{
var tabBarData:Array = new Array(
"Tab one",
"Tab two",
"Tab three",
"Tab four"
);
var tabBarGpl:TabBar = new TabBar();
tabBarGpl.dataProvider = new DataProvider(tabBarData);
tabBarGpl.selectedIndex = 0;
tabBarGpl.move(-230.95, -127.65);
this.addChild(tabBarGpl);
}
private function handleEvent(event:Event):void
{
var i:int;
switch (event.type)
{
case Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE :
displayInit();
removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleEvent);
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, handleEvent, false, 0, true);
this.tabBarGpl.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onTabBarClick);
}
}
private function onTabBArClick(event:Event):void
{
trace("tab bar clicked");
}
}
}
```

And... Nothing.  I see the TabBar with my Data on the 4 tabs, but no trace statement in the output.  Any advice would be helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Astra TabBar, but it looks to me like you're not calling your handleEvent() function initially. You need to add a listener for it when you instantiate your class. If handleEvent() doesn't get called, the click listener is never added and you won't see clicks.

```
public function TabBar() { //constructor function
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleEvent);
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you seem to be adding a new TabBar to each instance of TabBar that you create.

```
var tabBarGpl:TabBar = new TabBar();
tabBarGpl.dataProvider = new DataProvider(tabBarData);
tabBarGpl.selectedIndex = 0;
tabBarGpl.move(-230.95, -127.65);
this.addChild(tabBarGpl);
```

The keyword "this" here would refer to your TabBar instance and may cause this class to infinitely add new TabBars to exisitng TabBars.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your response to my post.  And thank you for your explaination about "this".  I didn't know that.

Comment: I still can't get this TabBar to work. (I removed the "this" to clean it up.) I have been adding, moving, reworking the EventListener for the tabbar and following the example from yahoo developer network... It seems like everyone uses this TabBar in Flex as opposed to Flash so there insn't a whole lot of documentation. I'll report back if I figure this out. If anyone has any more suggestions or knows about this, please help out.

Comment: It works now! But I now have more than 1 tabBar instance, each to show/hide their own number of movieclips. I placed the tabBar within a movieclip and called it with: mcMain01.tabBarGpl.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onTabBarClick);